# error 500 en mi sitio web, la pagina funciona con algunas limitaciones, no accede al escritorio del sitio con wp-admin

Tags: wordpress, error500

Cuando voy a ingresar al escritorio de WordpPress, a través del wp-admin, sale error 500, ademas aparece el mismo error al navegar por el menú de la página.

De inmediato me puse en contacto con el equipo de soporte donde está alojado el sitio web, el chico de soporte no puedo darme una solución, sin embargo probé buscando error en PHP, deshabilité un plugin que aparece en la pantalla de error (wordfence), cambié la versión PHP, dado que aun sigue el error, el chico de soporte no dio con la solución... sigo con el problema.

Comment: Convendría que revises el log de errores o que actives temporalmente el modo debug en WordPress.